# displaying a image created with chunkypng directly (w/o saving)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image, encoding

so i created a PNG image using [chunky_png](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png). i don't want to save this image, because its only useful for this one request, so i'm trying to save this image as an instance variable and displaying it in my view.

the problem is that this results in an `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` error in my view.

what i did:

```
# controller
@img = source_img.resize(200, 200).to_string

#view
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= @img %>" />
```

debugging the @img variable with `raise @img.to_yaml`  outputs me the correct string, f.e.:

```
--- !binary |-
    iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADIAQAAAACFI5MzAAACP0lEQVR4nO1Y
    QY6jQAy0AxJ9a34AH8l29lmRhgDJSDxrwsxHmh80N5Ag3urkjFZabTw5TJ+g
    HclWUa6ys5Ots6Ot8xP5/xFhnJIGxo/GdDD9HC+al6iNMpGFVie3kXOiyZET
    8bq49cAipRn5bVXOB+CVPiXPXyMRhQb1PDvPRmQZAMWOam/cN1TgpKFEyIVT
    pENLDF6oVoCuSCkdSIokEJnICy41K+AojX4psutY5+8011m80O1T4YpXxsOJ
    3mjqo2A8Jc+/RD7txVNhWFrJPDnTF41uBfPvoXKJHw/jjt7QLMThqKuj2Ufe
    +bUEFDeigtykr1UsVQkT2TP0cjA0H6wuR4VPkKilmMCDACjISmhLXc/64Ap+
    mp3RJZ3IFTVpe9aXXHxawKzOY/Ss8WCVHX2u7hjYNa/yxNsWSrEULzJT0Cd1
    XgToXEDWx/WgWRtPHKkZGSJ86ccDHjqvy9E1ryHfKORkmwJ+5u7NoqoUoXXQ
    axqTYS6Ng2jWukoBD6/7qI+2sc2AmUIKLnUxkHzFMDURVXdHx3hT97pd8hU6
    v9B8Ghs0qOnhIO9PybMZQRuumKTM42Ii3o2zew2lYLnBvRKP9ryErjeEd10/
    fexmaznti8ZWbopoJV5XKeIGJp6TUEEyDGVXZbV8bGCMqRPbTyQnlpDjNzAk
    gZXbNhxLINKH5+XZjsxsJD8DAwjGPtf+CnEDI8xVIX4HQ4aDtlLEDSzx5hdk
    M77FuUp5/9mKPHazu5LX97+wMH42qhX8RP4AQpEyh+7r4x0AAAAASUVORK5C
    YII=
```

copiing this string manually into the img tag displays the image correctly.

any ideas whats going wrong here? other ideas of displaying this image directly without saving?

thanks in advance! if something is unclear, PLEASE leave a comment.

Comment: have you tried adding to_yaml to your src attr?

Comment: @Yule `.to_yaml` does not crash my application, but of course the image will not get displayed, because of the yaml formatting.

Comment: bit of a hack, but what about .to_yaml.to_s ?

Comment: no, doesn't. what does work is `.to_string.to_yaml.gsub('--- !binary |-','')` but i think thats the worst way to do it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ChunkyPNG actually comes with a built-in function to do just this: `to_data_url`.

```
# controller
@img = source_img.resize(200, 200)

# view
<img src="<%= @img.to_data_url %>" />
```

It's implemented like this:

```
['data:image/png;base64,', @img.to_blob].pack('A*m').gsub(/\n/, '')
```

Make sure you're using the latest version of ChunkyPNG.

Comment: does rails provide a helper method for displaying images with data-strings?

Answer (score 6):

The @wvanbergen way gave me some errors, but I changed a little and it worked.

```
    #controller
    @png = qr.to_img.resize(250,250).to_data_url 

    #view
    <%= image_tag @png %>
```